# Import Mockup in XML using Balsamiq

Tags: json, xml, mockups, balsamiq

Does anyone know how to import XML into Balsamiq from http://webdemo.balsamiq.com/

I've have some mockup which I did last year, and I remember all the import and export were in XML format. Now they change to JSON format, I'm wondering how could I get back my old mockup source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Rename it to bmml extension, then Import BMML Mockups.
Once done, export it into JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

Export to BMML, unzip and copy and paste XMLs